# Create a header which expands beyond the right hand range of Foundation 6 grid

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6 grid to create a web page footer.  I would like to have the green bar extend beyond the range of the grid to the edge of the screen.

The attached screenshot shows how I am using 4 and 8 columns, but I need the top green bar to extend beyond the grid.

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this with CSS?

[image: css footer mockup]

Comment: You could try using absolute positioned pseudo elements, but it is hard to tell without seeing a working example of your code.

Comment: Thanks - I have it cracked using absolute positioning (almost) I'll post a pen once it's finalised

Comment: Good to hear. You will probably need to have a wrapper div around all your HTML with `overflow:hidden;` to prevent a horizontal scroll bar appearing.